# How do you specify the security domain for a war under JBoss 7?

Tags: java, security, jboss, jboss7.x

This line in my jboss-web.xml:

```
<security-domain>java:/jaas/flockingfun</security-domain>
```

produces this error:

`Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[3,19]
Message: Unexpected element 'security-domain' encountered
    at org.jboss.as.metadata.parser.util.MetaDataElementParser.unexpectedElement(MetaDataElementParser.java:109)
    at org.jboss.as.metadata.parser.jbossweb.JBossWebMetaDataParser.parse(JBossWebMetaDataParser.java:128)
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.JBossWebParsingDeploymentProcessor.processDeployment(JBossWebParsingDeploymentProcessor.java:60)
    ... 14 more`

Any ideas what I should be specifying? Thanks in advance.

Comment: isn't jboss 7 still in development?

Comment: Does your jboss-web.xml declare a schema (either XML schema or DTD) for the document?

Comment: I've tried declaring the 5.0 dtd, and not.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE jboss-web PUBLIC "-//JBoss//DTD Web Application 5.0//EN"
  "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-web_5_0.dtd">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JBoss AS7 does not yet have support for security domains.

Comment: Hey @rich can you elaborate please? I mean it did work for me, so how come you're so confident?

Comment: @rich This answer is no longer correct.  JBoss AS 7 *DOES* support security domains!  https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossAS7SecurityDomainModel

Answer (score 4):

Since I stumbled upon this question recently, and it didn't help as the JBoss 7 nowadays does support security domains, here is how:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
   <security-domain>flockingfun</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

There's no need to prefix it with `java:/jaas`.